# What is the correct way to extend mysqli for performance?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am extending mysqli in one of my classes. It works perfectly but the connection adds ~1 second to the php load time. I am wondering if there's a faster or more suitable way of connecting to MySql, or if there are database enhancements I can build for faster execution?

The 1 second overhead is purely the connection on my WAMP server, this is before I run any other queries.

Any ideas?

Thanks

```
class db extends mysqli {
    //ACCESS VARIABLES FOR ENTIRE SITE
    protected $_host = 'myhost';
    protected $_user = 'myuser';
    protected $_pass = 'mypass';
    protected $_db = 'mydb';

    function __construct() {
       echo microtime(true)."<br />";
           parent::__construct($this->_host, $this->_user, $this->_pass, $this->_db);
       if ($this->connect_errno) die('Connect Error: ' . $this->connect_errno);
       $this->set_charset("utf8");
           echo microtime(true)."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using windows, I always found WAMP/XAMP for windows terribly slow... Are you sure your extension 'adds' to the load time? (how fast is `new mysqli(params...)`)

Comment: Try using the IP address instead of the host. It might be a DNS issue.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried removing the `echo` statements to see if that improves run time?

I'll refer you to the Mysqli documentation page for alternate ways to connect: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

Comment: A question is not an answer. And just showing some docs neither.